# Filter Pandas dataframe with another series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have Pandas Series we'll call approved_fields which I'd like to use to filter a df by:

```
approved_field(['Field1','Field2','Field3')]

df
    Field
0   Field1
1   Field4
2   Field2
3   Field5
4   Field2
```

After applying the approved_field filter, the resulting df should look like:

```
    Field
0   Field1
1   Field2
2   Field2
```

Thanks!

Comment: The title needs fixing.  The terms "dataframe" and "series" have technical definitions that are do not fit their use in this question.  A dataframe is not a series.  Moreover, you are filtering with a list, which is neither a dataframe nor a series.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `isin` and boolean indexing:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Field": "Field1 Field4 Field2 Field5 Field2".split()})
>>> approved_fields = "Field1", "Field2", "Field3"
>>> df['Field'].isin(approved_fields)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Field, dtype: bool
>>> df[df['Field'].isin(approved_fields)]
    Field
0  Field1
2  Field2
4  Field2
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you indices in your expected solution are off

```
In [16]: approved_field = ['Field1','Field2','Field3']

In [17]: df = DataFrame(dict(Field = ['Field1','Field4','Field2','Field5','Field2']))

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
    Field
0  Field1
1  Field4
2  Field2
3  Field5
4  Field2

In [19]: df[df.Field.isin(approved_field)]
Out[19]: 
    Field
0  Field1
2  Field2
4  Field2
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I fixed this in my OP

Comment: Correct answer, DSM just beat you by 2 minutes!

Comment: that's what they say about the hare and the rabbit :)