# Filter date range for week of month

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file that I read via `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv`.

I want to filter those rows which contains 3rd Friday of a certain month or any months in the date index or in one of the columns.

I played around with `dateutil` and `pandas.datetools.WeekOfMonth(week=2,weekday=4)`
but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Could you post an example data from your csv?

Answer (score 0):

An example of your csv file would help us answer your question. I'm assuming you are using timestamps, is that true?

You could try filtering by making a list of the timestamps (the start and end dates here are arbitrary, and will likely come as the first and last row in your csv file):

```
start_date='1/1/2010'
finish_date='10/1/2010'

third_friday_timestamps = pd.date_range(start_date,finish_date, freq='WOM-3FRI')
```

this will give a Series of timestamps.  Using this series, you can filter the dataframe that came from the csv file using strategies explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046823/filter-pandas-dataframe-with-another-series?rq=1).  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. However,

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. However, I need the 3rd Saturday of the month, such as WOM-3SAT. I tried WOM-3SAT as the date_range-frequency, but got an error. I tried via 3rdfriday_timestamps+pandas.tseries.offsets.Day(1) but got an error again. Is that frequency unsupported? Are there any alternatives? And-I couldn't find any detailed documentations of which frequencies are supported within pandas.date_range and I wasn't even aware of the r3d Friday frequency. (I'm quite new to Pandas) Is there any good docs?

Comment: @user3276418  If that helps and you officially accept my answer, I could use the reputation, thanks!                      It only works for weekdays.  Here is some documentation that might help you get around that if you need a day on the weekend: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html